# Any pythonic way to auto determine imbalance class problem, specially in multiclass scenario?

Tags: python, class-imbalance

A data is imbalanced if a target class proportions are unequal and typically, heavily biased. But, **what is the exact measurement of this heavy bias**?

Before applying imbalance techniques (SMOTE, ADASYN, Tree classifiers,  etc.), I want to auto detect if problem belongs to imbalance class problem.

Comment: This may be helpful https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/283170/when-is-unbalanced-data-really-a-problem-in-machine-learning

Comment: [Class imbalance is not a problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he), and there is no need to determine the degree of imbalance to solve a non-problem.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your dataset, I would say you can set the threshold yourself.

For example, a 50% split is a perfect balance so by definition any deviation away would be an imbalanced problem. That being said, this is quite typical, so it would make more sense to set your threshold to be somewhere around 80% imbalance or higher.

Count your classes and set a threshold, e.g.

```
threshold = 80
imbalance_measure = (minority_class/majority_class)*100
if imbalance_measure >= threshold:
    print("Imbalanced problem")
else:
    print("Balanced problem")
```

In fact, if you data is suitable you can test this yourself through cross-validation

Some [further relevant documents here](https://thecleverprogrammer.com/2021/01/02/imbalanced-dataset-in-machine-learning/)

Comment: Any standard way to generalize for multi class problem say 10 classes ?

Comment: Not that I know of. If you have your data in a pandas dataframe you could do something like `df.groupby(['class']).count() / len(df['class'])`